# Need to exit function but getting none is not an allowed value error

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I have a condition where I have to exit the function that requires a type but I am returning None and Pydantic is giving the error: **none is not an allowed value (type=type_error.none.not_allowed)**

```
@schedules_router.post("/schedules/", status_code=201, response_model=DishSchedule)
def create_schedule(*, schedule_in: CreateDishSchedule) -> DishSchedule:
    """
    Create a new schedule (in memory only)
    """
    global counter
    new_entry_id = counter
    dishtype = schedule_in.dishtype
    # check to see if EVENTS is empty
    if len(EVENTS) == 0:
        print("No EVENTS found!")
        return None
    # check to see if SCHEDULES is empty
    if len(SCHEDULES) == 0:
        print("SCHEDULES is empty")
    else:
        print("SCHEDULES is not empty")
    preptime = 0
    schedule_entry = DishSchedule(
        id=new_entry_id,
        dishhost=schedule_in.dishhost,
        dishname=schedule_in.dishname,
        dishtime=preptime
    )
    SCHEDULES.append(schedule_entry.dict())
    counter += 1
    return schedule_entry
```

I plan not to return anything if the dictionary EVENTS is empty and simply exit the function.  What is the proper way to handle this without Pydantic throwing errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function clearly states, that the return value is `-> DishSchedule`. If you `return None`, your function is returning `None` and not `DishSchedule`. You could change the return value to `-> DishSchedule | None` (>= Python 3.10) or `Union[DishSchedule, None]` (< Python 3.10).
The alternative would be to raise an exception which you then handle outside the function:

```py
    if len(EVENTS) == 0:
        raise Exception("No EVENTS found!")
```